# Login em um site na web pelo programa

Tags: php, c#, mysql

Eu tenho um site programado em PHP com login e estou fazendo um aplicativo para desktop (Windows) e estou tentando fazer um login nele a partir desses sistema na web.

O meu sistema no PHP funciona da seguinte maneira: ele cria uma sessão no PHP e armazena os dados pertinentes à sessão em um Cookie. O sistema de autorização possuem 4 retornos: 1, quando há sucesso ao logar, -1 quando a senha está incorreta, -2 quando o usuário está incorreto e por fim, -3 quando o usuário erra a senha mais de 5 vezes em menos de 1 hora (anti Brute Force).

Eu consegui um código pesquisando na web (vou ficar devendo as referências, faz um tempo que achei) e ele é funcional: se eu tento logar no meu site com minhas credenciais, o retorno é 1, caso haja algum erro, os retornos estão corretos também.

O grande problema é conseguir "segurar" essa sessão. Quando fechamos o navegador por exemplo, vou estar logado quando abrir pois o Cookie vai estar "segurando" a sessão. Para fazer esse teste, criei uma página `logged.php`, e basicamente o retorno é 'Logado' para quando estiver logado e o contrário caso não.

No navegador, funciona normalmente, já no meu programa estou sempre deslogado!

Segue o meu método `login()`, responsável por todo o trabalho:

```
private void login()
{
    string formUrl = "http://exemplo.com.br/auth.php";
    string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username.Text, password.Text);
    string cookieHeader;
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
    MessageBox.Show(cookieHeader);
    string pageSource;
    string getUrl = "http://exemplo.com.br/logged.php";
    WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
    getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
    WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(pageSource);
    }
}
```

Tenho algumas outras sub-perguntas como: Fazer isso é seguro? Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer os retornos e adicionar dados? Seria usando um POST/GET para uma página com um SELECT no MySQL? Mas deixamos isso para depois!

Comment: Eu acho que facilitaria muito você ter uma API separada pro software desktop em vez de fazer o login tradicional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize o CookieContainer():

```
string formUrl = "http://exemplo.com.br/auth.php";
string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username.Text, password.Text);
string cookieHeader;

var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // coloque essa linha

var request = WebRequest.Create(formUrl) as HttpWebRequest; // linha modificada
//algumas modificaçoes abaixo
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

// removi uns codigos aqui, nao precisa ler a resposta do servidor manualmente.
request.GetResponse(); 

string getUrl = "http://exemplo.com.br/logged.php";
var getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
getRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        //ESCREVE A SAIDA:
        MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Referencia: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461960/login-session-not-transferring-to-new-webpage-using-webrequest-response)

Na questão da segurança, favor ver a resposta do @chambelix que esta muito bem explicada.

Comment: Você disse que eu não preciso ler a resposta do servidor manualmente.. Como verifico se a senha foi digitada erroneamente, por exemplo?

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski, acho que ele quis dizer que não precisa ler a resposta se o objetivo é só testar o retorno da requisição a página `logged.php`. É claro que pra saber se a senha foi digitada errada vai precisar processar o retorno da requisição a página `auth.php` sim.

Comment: Como o @Wakim falou, eu so coloquei que nao precisava processar o retorno pelo fato de nao necessitar pegar o cookie ja que o CookieContainer fará isso automaticamente.
Mas caso voce necessite pegar o retorno do  request.GetResponse(); e processar igual fiz nas ultimas linhas do codigo pode ficar a vontade.

Comment: Entendo! Muito obrigado, consigo andar com minhas próprias pernas a partir daqui!

Answer (score 2):

Encontro-me a desenvolver um projeto onde a essencia é quase a mesma... Um software desktop que acede a um sistema php e mysql que detém as identidades dos utilizadores.

Ao ler a sua pergunta e ao observar alguma preocupação sobre questões de segurança e sobre defesas de possiveis ataques, queria informar que um sistema que grava conteúdos em cookies a segurança claramente não é um ponto... Ou seja nunca confiar os dados vindos do cliente sendo um cookie facilmente manipulável.

Depois muitos outros níveis tem de ser levados em conta como acessos concurrentes, autenticidade de utilizadores, etc...

Um cookie deve quanto muito deter o Session_Id e no lado do servidor lidar com a sessão de forma segura, mas isso é outra guerra.

Comment: Concordo, mas imagino que o maior problema seja o sequestro de sessões, sobretudo com o 'man-in-the-middle' e trojans. A minha dúvida é sobre quem deve garantir a segurança: o PHP ou o C# ou ambos e como!

Comment: Sim Session Hijacking também é um problema real... Mas com SSL é uma boa gestão de sessões é impraticável... Apesar de existir quem proclame que consiga violar o "https". No entanton sera sempre o jogo do gato e do rato. Quem deve garantir a segurança é sempre quem detém as identidades.

Comment: E quem acede ao serviço web deve de garantir se o sistema é realmente seguro. Se ambos os sistemas forem desenvolvidos pelo mesmo...então a implementaçao de segurança depende muito das necessidades tanto para o serviço que detém as identidades como para o software que acede a esse serviço.

Comment: Correto, mas já não sei se é necessário o investimento em um certificado SSL. Não sei qual vai ser o tamanho do projeto (as expectativas são sempre gigantes), nunca saberei até onde crescerá, então no momento eu acho banal. Vi que você tem um certo conhecimento com segurança, será que seria possível 'prever' ou verificar se a informação tá sendo interceptada, seja pelo usuário ou pelo meu app?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... não pude incluir esses dados na minha por falta de conhecimento na area de segurança. Acredito que a pergunta agora esta muito bem respondida.

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski como disse depende muito das necessidades de cada projeto. Se for uma situação pessoal de uso interno a segurança depende de si. Se for para um serviço em que outros irão ter de confiar... então a segurança é algo que deve de investir conhecimento. A pergunta que faz é para o software desktop? ou para o lado do servidor?

Comment: Para o lado do Software!