# Como Logar em site utilizando PHP+Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo integração de 3 sistemas externos que individualmente tem suas autenticações. Cada um faz uma consulta de pessoas, tenho login e senha de todos, e nenhum tem Web Service. Sou iniciante no assunto de HTTPrequest, URLConnection, etc... Já pesquisei bastante o assunto mas estou com dificuldades. pelo que entendi eu devo usar o request preenchendo um cabeçalho, que ainda não sei qual a melhor maneira de descobrir. passando a autenticação via cookie e assim permanecer logado para fazer a consulta lá dentro. Com PHP+javascript, por onde começo? O que achei mais perto do que preciso é [Login em um site na web pelo programa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33282/login-em-um-site-na-web-pelo-programa)

mas não consegui aplicar, por não entender como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, a melhor maneira de fazer isso é usando CURL

Você pode usar essa biblioteca para fazer isso
https://github.com/minkphp/MinkGoutteDriver
Ela conta com vários exemplos, e uma documentação no site, já usei para fazer vários projetos

Para fazer isso com CURL puro vocẽ vai ter que fazer o seguinte

**1 - Realizar um POST com o login e senha na url de login e capturar o Cookie para usar futuramente para o login**

Exemplo:

```
$ch = curl_init();                    // inicia o curl
$url = "http://www.site.com.br/post.php"; // Url para login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");//seta onde guardar os cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");//seta onde guardar os cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // POST true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=admin&senha=1234"); // Defina o que vai enviar
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // quer retornar uma resposta ?
$result = curl_exec ($ch); // executa e salva a resposta em $result
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // infos
curl_close ($ch); // fecha a conexão

//Extrai o cookie com base no login.
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
$cookie_json = json_encode($cookies);
$cookie_json = json_decode($cookie_json);
$cookie_final = $cookie_json->{'SESSIONID'}; //salva em uma var o cookie
```

**2 Realizar o post com o cookie que você acabou de capturar**

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.site.com.br/get_dados.php'); //Url para capturar algum dado que você deseja
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'SESSIONID={$cookie_final}');
$result = curl_exec
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```